# application: not a procedure scheme

Tags: racket

i am new to racket. I tried to do lab work, but...

```
    #lang scheme

(define lab2
  (lambda (currentList counter result)
    ((let countdown ((i (- (length currentList) 1)))
       (if (= i 0) (display result)
           (begin 
                 (if (pair? (list-ref currentList i))  ;1 if element is list
                     (if (> (+ 1 counter) result) ;1 if counter > currentResult 
                         ((set! counter (+ 1 counter)) (set! result (+ 1 result)) (countdown(- i 1))) ;2 then counter++, result++
                         ((set! counter (+ 1 counter)) (countdown(- i 1)))) ;2 else counter++
                     ((set! counter 0) (countdown(- i 1)))) ;1 else counter=0
                 ))))))
```

testing: `(lab2 '(9 9 9 (0) (0) (0) (0) 9 9 9 9 9 9 (0)9 9 (0) 9 9 9 9 9 9) 0 0)`

but getting this : `application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
  arguments.:
   #<void>`

How fix it?
Please help me((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your indentation expresses what you want, this would be the working version of your code:

```scm
(define lab2
  (lambda (currentList counter result)
    (let countdown ((i (- (length currentList) 1)))
      (if (= i 0)
          (display result)
          (begin 
            (if (pair? (list-ref currentList i))  ;1 if element is list
                (if (> (+ 1 counter) result) ;1 if counter > currentResult
                    (begin
                      (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
                      (set! result (+ 1 result))
                      (countdown(- i 1))) ;2 then counter++, result++
                    (begin
                      (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
                      (countdown(- i 1)))) ;2 else counter++
                (begin
                  (set! counter 0)
                  (countdown(- i 1))))))))) ;1 else counter=0
```

Lessons learned:

- indent properly; especially don't put 2 consecutive forms on one single line
- in an `if` form, if you need to use a `begin` form if you have more than one form in the *then* or *else* part and **not** double parentheses
- if you use many `begin`with `if` you should try and see if using `cond` instead of `if` wouldn't make your code more readable (left as an exercise to you)
- if you have many `set!` forms you're probably not thinking *the Scheme way*; seriously, post another question where you explain what you want to do and a working version of this code!

Comment: Thank you so much!! You really helped me!!

Comment: Isn't it better form to use `add1` than to use `+ 1`?

Comment: @Fawful There's a lot of things to change here, not using `add1` is the least of all problems.